# Google App Script fails when trying to send more than one row of data

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I’m trying to send an email with user-defined rows in an HTML table. The user loads the sidebar and then fills out in an HTML form up to 5 rows they want to be included in the email template.

I seem to be able to get it to work with one row but as soon as I call the variables for more than one row it stops sending and I haven’t figured out how to error check yet.

Html Sidebar with the Script in the tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
       
       
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.emailAgent(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Select the Email Reponse Type and Input Row number.</p>

<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  <label for="templates">Rows:</label>
  <br>
  <div>
  <input type="text" name="rowOne" placeholder="Row 1" style="width:192px;" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" name="rowTwo" placeholder="Row 2" style="width:192px;" />
  </div><div>
  <input type="text" name="rowThree" placeholder="Row 3" style="width:192px;" />
  </div><div>
  <input type="text" name="rowFour" placeholder="Row 4" style="width:192px;" />
  </div><div>
  <input type="text" name="rowFive" placeholder="Row 5" style="width:192px;" />
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Code.gs

```
function emailAgent(formObject){
  //-------Sheet and User-------
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  
  //-------Form Data-------
  var rowOne = formObject.rowOne;
  var rowTwo = formObject.rowTwo;
   
  //-------Row one Data-------
  var details = sheet1.getRange(rowOne, 11).getValue();
  
  //-------Row Two Data-------
  var detailsTwo = sheet1.getRange(rowTwo, 11).getValue(); 
  
  //-------Table Rows-------
  var tableRowOne = '<tr>'+
        '<td style="text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">'+ details +'</td>' +
       '</tr>';
  
  var tableRowTwo = '<tr>'+
        '<td style="text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">'+ detailsTwo +'</td>' +
       '</tr>'+
          
   const message = "";
  var subject =  "Request to add " + date;
  var body =   
    '<body>' +
    '<table>' + 
    tableHeaders +
    tableRowOne +
    tableRowTwo +
    endOfEmail +
    '</body>';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'from': alias,'replyTo': alias,htmlBody: body});  

  }
```

Comment: I would consider helping if you would provide a [mcve] with emphasis on the minimal.  I don't really care if it takes you more work as long as it saves me some time reading your code.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the feedback. I've tried to cut it down a lot. If you are able to provide some insight I'd appreciate it. Thanks